# Equivalent Exchange: Adding block IDs from other mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I am using the Technic pack for Minecraft 1.0.0 and have added Equivalent Exchange. EE is wonderful, and can transmute any vanilla item to any other. However, the blocks added by IndustrialCraft^2, BuildCraft, and other mods aren't available to EE.

Question: Does anyone know of a way to use a config file or other tool to specify the EMC values of non-vanilla blocks and entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an extension to EE, ostensibly included with the default install, to add some things from IC^2; but it is broken.

<del>A patch is floating around the EE Wiki, and after it is applied, it should work perfectly.</del> This patch has since been removed by a moderator, sorry.

Insofar as I can recall, it adds rubber saplings, bronze, tin and copper, and some dusts, to the things that are transmutable.

I don't know that it adds anything from BC, but it does interface with it, so that seems to be intentional.

Comment: 'floating around the EE Wiki' - can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @fredley: Unfortunately, no. It has since been removed.

Comment: Thanks for looking that up! Perhaps it is time to try my hand at modding...

Comment: @JesseSmith: The issue in question will likely be resolved in an upcoming version of EE.